# Design Question: Low load data aggregation for overview page

Tags: django, postgresql

What is the best way to achieve low load on the database or application server for this use case:

Let's say I want to build a web application that has for each user an overview page. The overview page shows in an aggregated form for each user the user's data. For example, if it were a library application it would show how many times the user visited the library in total, how many books he read in total, how many books were delivered delayed in total, how many minutes he spend in the building. Each time the user visits the overview page the up-to-date values should be displayed. While the user interacts with the site the numbers change.

What I could do is for every overview page refresh do several counts in the database. But that would be expensive.

**views.py**

```
def overview(request, userID):
    booksCount = Book.objects.count()
    booksReadCount = Book.objects.filter(UserID=userID, Status='read').count()
    # ... many more, same way
    libraryVisitedCount = LibraryVisits.objects.filter(UserID=userID).count()
    # many counts like these on different tables for the user

    data = {
        "booksCount" : booksCount,
        "booksReadCount" : booksReadCount,
        # ... many more
        "libraryVisitedCount" : libraryVisitedCount
    }

    render(..., context=data)
```

I have thought I could store a JSON object with the data to be presented on the overview page in a database table and I update the JSON each time an event happend on the site which affects the count of objects.

Or I could use a materiliazed view but to refresh it I would have to recalculate all the data of all users each time, right?

Other ideas? I'm using django webframework and postgres database.

**TL;DR:** I wondered isn't there a better way to receive counts than do several counts in the database each time?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably you are looking for django annotation and conditional expressions. If you could add more code, we might be help you out regarding this.

Comment: @ruddra, I added some illustration code as I haven't yet started coding this part. It's not so much about aggregating the values but more about storing the aggregation for later and keeping it up to date continuously.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say, in `Book`, `LibraryVisit` etc models, there is ForeignKey to User model with [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='books', on_delete=DO_NOTHING)

class LibraryVisit(models.Model):
    UserID = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='library_visit', on_delete=DO_NOTHING)
```

Then you can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) and [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Sum, When

def overview(request, userID):
    users = User.objects.filter(pk=userId)
    users = users.annotate(
            booksReadCount=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(book__Status='read', then=1), 
                    output_field=IntegerField()
                )
            )
        ).annotate(library_visited_count=Count('library_visit'))
    # FYI: please use snake_case when defining object attribute(like model fields) as per PEP-8 style guide
    data = {
        "user_object" : users.first(),  # taking first item of the User queryset. Also DB is hit once in this step
        "booksCount" : Book.objects.count()
    }
    # access counts in view like this:
    # user.book_read_count
    # user.library_visited_count
    return render(..., context=data)

    # bold marked words are related_name
```

And render counts in template like this:

```
{{ user_object.book_read_count }}
{{ user_object.library_visited_count }}
```